# use of creating a patch file in svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

anyone of you please clear the following doubt.                                                             for testing purpose i made changes in the document which is in the trunk folder later on i  create a patch for the same file. after creating the patch, then i made the changes in the same document,committed it and applied the patch to the same file. but the changes what i made after creating the patch file are also visible in the patch file. i don't know why. it would be very helpful if anyone help in this.

thanks in advance,

prasad

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you create a .patch file with tortoisesvn is that you literally create a file that contains the difference between your working copy and the most recent commit. You're then able to apply this .patch file to any other working copy to move your changes around with having to make commits.

So if you created a .patch then committed your change, then yes, the change will be both in the committed file AND in the .path file - because that's what its for!